# User Authentication. Database lookup vs RPC call

Tags: database, rpc

If we have more than one service that uses same database - is it ok to move out user authentication on separate server and use RPC calls, instead of traditional database lookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a dedicated service for user authentication is a good evolution of your service model because it provides a layer of indirection between the database and the client services. This allows you to evolve the data model without necessarily impacting other services. Moving user entitlements (authorization) out of the database has similar benefits.

Comment: I'm thinking also. You improved my believe in this solution. :)